# Change integer value to string or insert mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that does a count, but I need to add mask to this value. The final value is 3000 only that I need for 3,000;

is there any way to change the integer value to another format and still do the count inside the function itself?

Following function:

```js
function numerosHome(id, inicialValor, valorFinal){
  var inicial = inicialValor;
  var location = document.getElementById(id);
  var contador = setInterval(() => {
      location.innerHTML = inicial;
      inicial++;
      var final = valorFinal +1;
      if(inicial == final){
          clearInterval(contador);
      }
  },0.5);
}
numerosHome('numeros', 2800, 3000);
```

```css
#numeros{
font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numeros">
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using an interval there instead of some for loop?  `0.5` is effectively 1/2 a millisecond.  There's no reason to use an interval there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need?

We can call `toLocaleString` on the number to get the formatting

```js
function numerosHome(id, inicialValor, valorFinal){
  var inicial = inicialValor;
  var location = document.getElementById(id);
  var contador = setInterval(() => {
      // Format the numner to toLocaleString before setting the innerHTML
      location.innerHTML = inicial.toLocaleString();
      inicial++;
      var final = valorFinal +1;
      if(inicial == final){
          clearInterval(contador);
      }
  },0.5);
}
numerosHome('numeros', 2800, 3000);
```

```css
#numeros{
font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numeros">
</div>
```